# Mocking functions for handler unit test

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I am stuck over testing with mocking, Here is my route for handler:

```
r.Handle("/users/{userID}", negroni.New(
        negroni.HandlerFunc(validateTokenMiddleware),
        negroni.Wrap(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            getUserDetailsHandler(w, r, db)
        })),
    )).Methods("GET")
```

And here is my handler:

```
func getUserDetailsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, db *sql.DB) {

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")

    //Create UserDetailsView instance
    var userview UserDetailsView

    //Get varibale from mux
    vars := mux.Vars(r)

    //UserID  fetches userId from vars
    userID := vars["userID"]

    //Get user Information by wpUsersID
    wuis := store.NewWpUserInformationStore(db)
    userInformation, _:= wuis.GetByID(uID)


        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(userview); 

        //Print result
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

And i mock the function which is in store package named as `GetByID` which is looks like this :

```
type wpUserInfoMockStore struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *wpUserInfoMockStore) GetByID(user *WpUserInformation) error {
    rets := m.Called(user)
    return rets.Error(0)
}

//InitMockStore store
func InitMockStore() *wpUserInfoMockStore {
    s := new(wpUserInfoMockStore)
    //store = s
    return s
}
```

And i write test case for handler but i got an error `cannot convert getUserDetailsHandler (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, *sql.DB)) to type http.HandlerFunc` but i can not find why is it happened, here i'm using reference for this `https://github.com/sohamkamani/blog_example__go_web_db` and here is my test case code:

```
func TestGetUserDetailsTes(t *testing.T) {

    // Initialize the mock store
    mockStore := store.InitMockStore()

    mockStore.On("GetByID").Return([]*store.WpUserInformation{{
        21,
        sql.NullString{String: "john"},
        sql.NullString{String: "Sorensen"},
        0}}, nil).Once()

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "", nil)

    //if requests gives error
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    //parameters for generateTestUserJWT are set
    testUser.ID = "22"
    testUser.UserName = "johns"
    testUser.Depot = "NYC"

    //JWT generated
    refToken, err := generateTestJWT(testUser, false)

    //handling error while generating token
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    //token returned is concatenated with Bearer string
    newToken = "Bearer " + refToken

    //request authorization header is set
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", newToken)
    req.Header.Set("Latitude", "123.12")
    req.Header.Set("Longitude", "456.45")

    //response is set
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()

    hf := http.HandlerFunc(getUserDetailsHandler)

    hf.ServeHTTP(w, req)

    //if response code is not statusOK then test fails
    if w.Code != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("/users/{userID} GET request failed, got: %d, want: %d.", w.Code, http.StatusOK)
    }
}
```

As you see i test handler without url like `req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "", nil)` but when i used link inside then i can not able to use mock functions, here what am i missing/fault please help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: The line in your test where you have `hf := http.HandlerFunc(getUserDetailsHandler)` is causing the panic, that should be clear from the stack trace that you didn't include. Now the reason it panics is because the signature of your `getUserDetailsHandler` function is different from the signare of the `http.HandlerFunc` function type. So basically you have two non-identical types and you're attempting to convert one to the other, which is impossible, therfore you get panic.

Comment: How could i solve this problem could you please write some code to call handler from test case. Thank you.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/5klOkOMO3LA

Comment: actually you should be able to just do this https://play.golang.org/p/_cFR3vyjkPr if the function `store.NewWpUserInformationStore(db)` already returns something that uses the `mockStore` instance. But as you can see from the code samples, to avoid the panic you just wrap you handler in a function the same way you do in your code snippet at the top of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a middleware handler for generating the function. Pass a handler in your main function which will call your middleware returning `http.handler`. That way you can pass db object to your main data and which will call the middle ware returning handler.

```
func getUserDetailsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, db *sql.DB) http.HandlerFunc{

    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")

        //Create UserDetailsView instance
        var userview UserDetailsView

        //Get varibale from mux
        vars := mux.Vars(r)

        //UserID  fetches userId from vars
        userID := vars["userID"]

        //Get user Information by wpUsersID
        wuis := store.NewWpUserInformationStore(db)
        userInformation, _:= wuis.GetByID(uID)


        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(userview); 

        //Print result
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
   }
}
```